# A system of 1st order nonlinear ODEs with 3 varibles.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I want to find a solution of a system of 1st order ODEs.

$Z_t=2(P^2+Q^2)$

$P_t=2PZ$

$Q_t=2QZ$

To solve this, I tried to differentiate the first equation and get

$Z_{tt}=4PP_t+4QQ_t=8Z(P^2+Q^2)=4ZZ_t$

which is a second order nonlinear ODE for Z.

If I find the solution of Z in general form, it is easy to find what P and Q is. However, It is hard to solve on Z and I failed.

Is there anyone who can solve that ODE for Z or can solve the system of ODEs on Z,P,Q in other ways?

Please help me. Thank you for your any comments or advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct so far. Therefore 
$$
Z'= 2Z^2 + C,
$$
where the constant $C$ can be determined from
$
C = Z'(0) - 2Z(0)^2 = P(0)^2 + Q(0)^2 - 2 Z(0)^2 \, .
$
This can now be solved via separation of variables.